How can I change the values in the tensor using dictionary?
when I have a tensor and dictionary as below, how can I map the dictionary to the tensor?
For example,
Dict = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}

ex = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]])

# Expected result
#tensor([[A, B, C],
#        [C, B, A]])

I tried this code and torch.where, but it didn't work well.

This link uses ex.apply_(Dict.get), does it work in your case?

# Define the dictionary and tensor
Dict = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}
ex = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]])

# Map the dictionary to the tensor
mapped_result = [[Dict[item.item()] for item in row] for row in ex]

# Convert to a string tensor if you want a list of lists
print(mapped_result)

Convert the list of lists back to a tensor if needed (as strings are not natively supported in PyTorch tensors, you might need to use a different structure like a list of lists or NumPy array if you want to store strings). But if you check the data type, it gives you dtype('U1') when using numpy array.

You can do that using this code snippet below:
import numpy as np
import torch


dic_items = {1: "A", 2: "B", 3: "C"}
tensor_nos = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]])
tensor_numpy = tensor_nos.numpy()
vectorize_map = np.vectorize(dic_items.get)(tensor_numpy)

results = vectorize_map.tolist()

# Print the result
print(results)

